# Unicity on two columns asymmetrically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, constraints, unique-constraint

This is my table `Friendship(user_id1:integer, user_id2:integer)`

I want to add a constraint to the database so that a couple of user_id will be rejected if its symetric already exists.

For example, if I already have the couple `(42, 17)` in the db, I don't want to be able to save `(17, 42)`

I'm using rails with postgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in the database using an index on expressions:

```
create unique index unq_friendship_1_2
     on (least(user_id1, user_id2), greatest(user_id1, user_id2));
```

I do not know how you express this in rails.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a combination of a normal unique constraint and a check constraint, if you are able to implement the application in a way, that it stores the smaller value in the field user_id_1 and the bigger value in the field user_id_2.

Define a unique constraint on (user_id_1, user_id_2) and additionally a check constraint, that (user_id_1 <= user_id_2) to verify that your application behaves in the way defined above.

In Oracle this would be

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD CONSTRAINT cname1 UNIQUE (user_id_1, user_id_2)
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD CONSTRAINT cname2 CHECK (user_id_1 <= user_id_2)
```

If your application is not able to insert the values sorted as described above, you still can use e.g. triggers, but this is more DB-vendor specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this in Rails.
In your rails model `friendship.rb`, add the following `validates_uniqueness` call:

`validates_uniqueness_of :user_id1, :scope => :user_id2`.
This guarantees that there will be no two identical couples of `user_id1`s or `user_id2`s.

However, [@potashin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3444240/potashin) has explained that this method is not totally safe because if two simultaneous requests are sent they may be accepted and your rows would be duplicated. His solution is to also add the following migration to your Friendships model:

```rb
class AddUniqueConstraints < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   add_index :friendships, [:user_id1, :user_id2], unique: true
  end
end
```